# Making Drupal user array into a dropdown

Tags: arrays, drupal, drop-down-menu, stdclass

I have a query that pulls all my drupal users into a stdClass_object, however I am having trouble getting these values out apart from using `print_r`. I would like to put them into a dropdown, however cannot get this working.

`stdClass Object ( [uid] => 0 [users_name] => )` Example of the array that is outputs

```
$result = db_query('SELECT users.uid AS uid,   users.name AS users_name FROM users users');
 $result_array = is_array($result);

 while ($existing_user = db_fetch_object($result)) {
 print_r($existing_user); // or do whatever
}

foreach ($existing_user->uid as $message) {
echo $message->users_name;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `pg_fetch_array()` or any other database-type specific functions.

Instead, just use Drupal's database functions and it will automatically adjust the queries.

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
function MYMODULE_get_users() {
  $users = array();
  $results = db_query("SELECT uid, name FROM {users}");
  foreach ($results as $user) {
    $users[$user->uid] = $user->name;
  }

  return $users;
}
```

And here's how you would use this code:

```
<select name="uid">
<?php foreach (MYMODULE_get_users() as $user): ?>
  <option value="<?php print $user->uid; ?>"><?php print $user->name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

However, you should be using Drupal's Form API to build forms. It will handle many things for you, including validation and submitting handling out of the box.

Check [this article](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7) for more information. Also, check out the source code of [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) modules, specifically examples related to Form API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do plan on using the form api, however I used the above code in a node and the drop down did not populate? Or how would i put this info a form?

Comment: The snippet works; however I'd say that there is an issue in the way you used the code in a node. Post the complete code so I can have a look.

Comment: I posted it (in a node, and i have pretty much allowed any code in the nodes for now), I would rather use it in a module (as you suggested) but if I can just get an en example working that would be great. Just a heads up im heaving to use drupal 6 too

Comment: Yes; it's a Drupal standard to call it just a `name` - to keep things consistent and less confusing later on, I suggest just keeping it that way.